# svg image to bitmap from assets folder

Tags: android, svg, bitmap, android-glide

Am trying to get svg image from assets folder and display it using glide.

```
try {
     InputStream imageStr = activity.getAssets().open("www/images/icons/svg/image.svg");
     Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStr);
     Glide.with(activity)
          .load(bitmap)
          .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_no_photo)
          .fitCenter()
          .into(title_image);
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: BitmapFactory.decodeStream() will not decode .svg files. Only .jpg and .png and webp and such. It will return null now. You can easily check that.

Comment: and try to used  imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable. ic_no_photo);

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can set an SVG file to imageview directly

what you can do is:

In drawable right click -> New -> Vector Asset -> Local SVG file.

now select your SVG file and use it like

```
android:src="@drawable/imageName"
```